# D3 exit(), remove() not working when the element is removed and added

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization

I have a histogram  that dynamically updates based on the input (country on map is clicked). The each bar has a mouseover info display.

While all the bars are update correctly at least visually, the mouseover menu will not appear on bars that were removed and added.

Here is the link to the project. For example, when I load histogram for Sweden after loading India, the mouseover display will not work correctly.

http://jbk1109.github.io/tennisMapWithPlayersListOnHover.html

```
//This is the function called when a country on the map is clicked

function drawBarChart(d){
    selectCountryName = event['path'][0]['__data__']['name']
    selectCountry = d.id    

    countryArray = d3.values(tennis).filter(function(d){
        return d.COUNTRY_ID == selectCountry
    })

/*
    1. Select existing bars
    2. Need the data array of existing bars.
    3. remove the data.
    4. remove the bar (the svg element)

    */

    var addRect = d3.select('g.nations').selectAll('rect')
              .data(countryArray)

              console.log(addRect.exit().remove())
              console.log(addRect.enter())
          addRect.enter()
          .append('rect')

          addRect.transition().duration(650)
          .attr({
                      x: function(d,i){ 
                            return(xScale(d.DATE))
                            // return (rectWidth(d.DATE)) 
                          },
                      y: function(d){ 
                         return (rectHeight + 50) - heightScale(d.COUNT) 
                      },
                      width: function(d){ 
                            return (width-150)/yearArray.length
                            // return rectWidth.rangeBand()
                          },
        height: function(d){ 
            return heightScale(d.COUNT)
          },
        fill: 'steelblue'
    }).attr('class','countryRect')



  var y = d3.select('g.nations').selectAll('text.count')
        .data(countryArray)

        y.exit().remove()

    y.enter()
    .append('text')
    y.transition().duration(650)
    .attr('class','count')
    .attr('x',function(d,i){
        return(xScale(d.DATE) + ((width-150)/yearArray.length)/2)
    })
    .attr('y', function(d){
      return (rectHeight + 50) - heightScale(d.COUNT) + 11
    })
    .text(function(d){
        return d.COUNT
    })
    .attr('text-anchor','middle')
}
```

//This is where to histogram is create initially upon load.

```
  var padding_right = 8
  var nations =    svg.append('g').attr("class","nations").attr('transform','translate('+ 30 +',10)')

var histSelection = nations.selectAll('rect.countryRect')
          .data(function(){
                    return d3.values(tennis).filter(function(d){
                          return d.COUNTRY_ID == 840;
                          })
            }).enter()

          histSelection.append('rect')
          .attr({
                  class: function(d){return "countryRect"},
                      x: function(d,i){ 
                            return(xScale(d.DATE))
                            // return (rectWidth(d.DATE)) 
                          },
                      y: function(d){ 
                          return (rectHeight + 50) - heightScale(d.COUNT)
                        },
                      width: function(d){ 
                            return (width-150)/yearArray.length
                            // return rectWidth.rangeBand()
                          },
        height: function(d){ 
           return heightScale(d.COUNT)},
        fill: 'steelblue'
    })



          // Add player count to at the top of each bar

    var countLabel = d3.select('g.nations').selectAll('text.count')
    .data(function(){
        return d3.values(tennis).filter(function(d){
          return d.COUNTRY_ID == 840;
        })
    })

    countLabel.enter()
    .append('text')
    .attr('class','count')
    .attr('x',function(d,i){
        return(xScale(d.DATE) + ((width-150)/yearArray.length)/2)
    })
    .attr('y', function(d){
      return (rectHeight + 50) -heightScale(d.COUNT) +11
    })
    .text(function(d){
        return d.COUNT
    })
    .attr('text-anchor','middle')
 var x_axis = nations.append('g').attr("class","xAxis").attr("transform", "translate(0," + (rectHeight+50) + ")").call(xAxis)
```

**Add mouseover event

```
  var selectRect = d3.select('g.nations').selectAll('.countryRect')
  selectRect.on('mouseover',function(d){

    console.log(d)
    d3.select('.divContainer').style('left',this.x.baseVal.value).style('left',this.x.baseVal.value + 'px').style('display','block')
    divContainer.style('top',this.y.baseVal.value).style('top',(this.y.baseVal.value+90) +'px')

    var playerList = d.players;
    playerList.sort(function(a,b){ return a.RANKING - b.RANKING})

    var table = divContainer.append('table')
    var headerRow = table.append('tr')
    headerRow.append('th').html("Ranking").attr("class",'ranking')
    headerRow.append('th').html("Name").attr("class",'name')

    var players = table.append('tbody').selectAll('tr').data(playerList).enter()
    var eachRow = players.append('tr')
    var eachCell1 = eachRow.append('td').attr('class','rankingCell').html(function(d){return d.RANKING})
    var eachCell2 =  eachRow.append('td').attr('class','nameCell').html(function(d){return d.PLAYER_NAME})

    // var addPlayers = players.append('text').text(function(d){
      // return d.PLAYER_NAME

  })
  .on('mouseout',function(d){
      d3.select('.divContainer').style('display','none')
      d3.select('.divContainer').select('table').remove()
  })
```

Comment: I have a hunch that post remove of bars(when you select india)
and then you select Sweden new bars are created..on these new bars you have not registered the mouseover mouse out code. try that it should solve your problem

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It seems to have solved the issue. I am curious though, when the bars are removed and added, shouldn't mouseover event be added to the new bars?

Comment: Pseudocode for my initial code: 1)Draw bar chart inside a function. 2) outside the function, select all the bar using selectAll('rect) and add mouseover event.

Comment: In your initial code... you draw the rectangles then attach listeners to it.
Now when you select India few of the bars are removed. and when you select spain new bars are added now these new bars are not registered to any events..you should be doing that, that was the missing link.